# Time to update our FAQ?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

The basic text in our [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) describing what's on topic comes from [the original Area 51 proposal for our site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles). In the first few months of our beta, we added a bit referring people to [on-off-topic](/questions/tagged/on-off-topic) on meta and [reference](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) on the site, but haven't otherwise changed it.

I think that instead of referring people to some meta threads, we should spell out what is and is not on-topic right there in the FAQ. I also think it's long enough since we had any real changes to defining what is on and off topic that we can safely put it in the FAQ.

I've gotten a bit of inspiration from:

- [The Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)
- [The DBA FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)
- [Current Server Fault FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions)
- [Proposed update to Server Fault FAQ](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2591/our-faq-sucks-so-lets-fix-it/2592#2592)

Here is the current text from the FAQ that we can change (the rest isn't ours to touch):

> Bicycles - Stack Exchange is for people
>   who build and repair bicycles, people who train cycling, or commute on
>   bicycles.
>
> If you're not quite sure if your question is on topic, consider
>   looking at [meta questions tagged
>   [on-off-topic]](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic)
>   where the community has discussed what questions are appropriate for
>   this site.
>
> If your question is fairly basic, you might find the answer in [one of
>   our growing reference
>   pages](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference).
>   Also, feel free to link to these in your questions and answers,
>   particularly the entries in the [terminology
>   index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index)
>   if you'd rather not re-invent the two-wheeler.

Answer (score 2):

## Working Draft

Bicycles - Stack Exchange is for people who
**build and repair bicycles**, **train bicycling**, or **commute on
bicycles**.

#### *If you have a question about...*

- Riding [technique](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) or [training](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training), on any surface, with any bicycle
- Bicycle [safety](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety), or [fit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bike-fit)
- [Maintenance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance), modification, [assembly](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/build), or [building](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frame-building)
- Bicycle [parts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts), [clothes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes), [security](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security), or bicycle-specific gadgets
- Understanding the tactics, strategies and rules of bicycle [racing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racing)
- Specific types of bikes or types of riding: [mountain bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-bike), [road bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/road-bike), [hybrids](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hybrid-bike), [folding bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folding-bicycle), [recumbents](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recumbent), or even [tricycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tricycle) or unicycles
- Questions about being or becoming a bicycle [commuter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commuting)

#### *... then you are in the right place to ask your question!*

#### *But this is not the right place to ask about...*

- Following professional racing (who will win, etc.)
- General fitness, losing weight or getting in shape (ask on [Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead)
- Designing, building or modifying an electronic gadget (ask on [Electronics Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead)
- Anything primarily powered by a motor instead of you (ask on [Mechanics instead](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead)

Comment: I personally dislike the use of tags in the FAQ. Makes it harder to read.

Comment: @nhinkle: I'm not particularly attached to using tags, and phrasing things so the tag wording worked in sentences got a little awkward. We can definitely drop them. What do you think, make some stuff regular links to tags, or just plain text?

Comment: I don't think tag links from the FAQ are necessary at all. To my knowledge, no other site does this.

Comment: @nhinkle: DBA and the proposed new SF FAQ do. But this one doesn't anymore. :)

Comment: hmm, so they do. It just seems so very cluttered to me. It makes the text not flow well to me. I suppose in-line links would be fine though.

Comment: Alternately, the tags can be formatted as links and not tags. (They'd still lead to the tagged questions.)

Comment: @NeilFein: I changed it so they're links now

Comment: @nhinkle - Does this work for you, or do you find it distracting to read?

Comment: @NeilFein I like it a lot better now, personally.

Comment: This draft has the same issue I see with the current wording already: "Bicycles - Stack Exchange is for people who build and repair bicycles, train bicycling, or commute on bicycles." - forthose who do it already? In my opinion it should be explicitthat we also like questions for people  who want toget started

Comment: I almost wish that last qualifier was "Anything powered by a motor instead of you (ask on Mechanics instead instead)."  Once you allow questions concerning eBikes (which are not a bicycle in my opinion) you open it up for questions about the motor and other mess that I'd really rather not see on here.